# how to monitoring cpu usage with counters all workers processes from some app pool in powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, application-pool, w3wp, performance-monitor

I found only these counters:
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Worker Processes Created
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Time Since Last Worker Process Failure
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Worker Process Ping Failures
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Worker Process Shutdown Failures
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Worker Process Startup Failures
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Current Application Pool State
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Worker Process Failures
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Recent Worker Process Failures
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Application Pool Uptime
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Current Application Pool Uptime
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Total Application Pool Recycles
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Maximum Worker Processes
\APP_POOL_WAS(*)\Current Worker Processes

No once CPU Usage

Comment: Firstly, please format your post. `What did do you search for?` [Either using the SO search box above](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+monitor+worker+processes) or the web in general? there are tons of articles, blogs, discussions very similar to what you seem to be after.

Comment: SO, has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Please Format your question properly ...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the performance monitor and PAL tools. With the PAL tool, you can export the performance counter template. The performance monitor is a built-in tool of Microsoft. Use the perfmon command to open the performance monitor.

Here is the reference: [How to Set up the PAL Tool for Windows Performance Monitoring](https://dev.to/adbertram/how-to-set-up-the-pal-tool-for-windows-performance-monitoring-4ki4)